# Google docs API: Width type must be provided when updating column width

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm using the google docs API and trying to set the width of a table column using `batchUpdate` that includes this request:

```
{
  'updateTableColumnProperties': {
    'tableStartLocation': {
      'index': my_table_index
    },
    'columnIndices': [my_column_index],
    'tableColumnProperties': {
      'widthType': "FIXED_WIDTH",
      'width': {
        'magnitude': my_width,
        'unit': 'PT'
      }
    },
    'fields': 'width'
  }
}
```

But I'm getting an error back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid requests[4].updateTableColumnProperties: Width type must be provided when updating column width.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

This is confusing.  I think I *am* specifying the widthType.  Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to specify `widthType` in `fields`:

BEFORE

```
        'fields': 'width'
```

AFTER

```
        'fields': 'width,widthType'
```

Here's the complete request:

```
{
  'updateTableColumnProperties': {
    'tableStartLocation': {
      'index': my_table_index
    },
    'columnIndices': [my_column_index],
    'tableColumnProperties': {
      'widthType': "FIXED_WIDTH",
      'width': {
        'magnitude': my_width,
        'unit': 'PT'
      }
    },
    'fields': 'width,widthType'
  }
}
```